# Get ToString from inherited class

Tags: c#

I'm writing a client to server and back ( send back ToString(); ) function as an school assignment.
Client will send code and server will see if code exists, send back ToString if found or else send exception error. I have made my own simple custom generic list (class ListForDB).

Created a class Card and with four different inherited class called with a ToString in each of those classes that will be called on based on the type.

The problem i have is that I'm having trouble to send back the ToString() from the inherited class. It will only get the ToString in class Card. And if i remove the ToString in Card it will only send back "Guldkortet_Server.Card"

And i don't really know how to solve it...

The method to load and save database to list

```cs
    public class SearchResult
    {
        public int index { get; set; } // save index of first search
        public int index2 { get; set; }
        public bool result { get; set; }
        public bool result2 { get; set; }
    }
    internal class ListingDB
    {   
        // Create object to store the list for account list and card list
        public ListForDB<Account> AccountList = new ListForDB<Account>();
        public ListForDB<Card> CardList = new ListForDB<Card>();

        public void LoadDBCard()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Data Source = (localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDBFilename = |DataDirectory|Kortregister.mdf; Integrated Security = true";

                string query = "SELECT KortNr, KortTyp FROM Kort";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // SEE IF PROBLEM LIES HERE?
                            Card newListItem = new Card(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            newListItem.type = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            CardList.Add(newListItem);
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                        connection.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                test.Message(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The Card class

```cs
public class Card
{
    public string cardID {  get; set; }
    public string type {  get; set; }
    protected bool claimed { get; set; }
    // CHECK COPY CONSTRUCTOR AND TOSTRING!!!!!!!
    public Card(string inCardID)
    {
        cardID = inCardID;
    }
    public virtual string ToString()        
    { return cardID + type + claimed; }
}
public class ÖverPanda : Card
{
    public ÖverPanda(string inCardID) : base(inCardID)
    {
        type = "Överpanda";
        claimed = true;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return cardID + "###" + type + "###" + claimed;
    }
}
```

Here is how i handle the result after checking if values from client are all true

`var returnMessage = reference.AccountList[searchRef.index].ToString() + reference.CardList[searchRef.index2].ToString();`

I expected to get the override ToString() from the inherited classes. But i did not. it will just step into the ToString in the class Card...

Comment: Protip: OOP inheriance doesn't solve problems, it only creates them.

Comment: Side notes: `AttachDBFilename` in the conenction string is a bad idea. Instead just attach your database normally in SSMS using `CREATE DATABASE`, then specify that database name in your connection string. `reader` needs a `using`. And you don't need to manually close the connection if you have `using` on it.

Comment: Thanks, have edited the code for using on reader now. And i will try the CREATE DATABASE

Comment: @Dai able to elaborate on that statement?, Your comment seems to suggest nothing beneficial comes from inheritance. the netcore source code itself makes use of it

Comment: @DenisMicheal I strongly recommend everyone read this article: https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/ - _in summary_: Java-style OOP is very 1990s; FP is better and it's here to stay.